# Get key from Uri in CreateRef (.NET Core 6 OData)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-6.0

While upgrading to OData 8, could not find a way to fetch key from the URI for navigation property.

I'm using preview package of [Asp.Versioning.OData](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Asp.Versioning.OData) and following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/entity-relations-in-odata-v4) from Microsoft to fetch key from Uri. This guid has a method `Helpers.GetKeyFromUri()` but with OData v8, it has many extension methods missing such as `GetUrlHelper()` or types like `KeyValuePathSegment`.

Is there a new way to extract key from Uri when using Asp.Versioinng.OData with OData 8 and .net core 6?

I also referred to its [source with examples](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/blob/be7db0422982357919df8f9a531516d499add664/examples/AspNetCore/OData/ODataOpenApiExample/V3/AcmeController.cs#L45) but it did not implement how to fetch the key from Uri.

Comment: It looks like this may already be answered? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63250958/2208058

Comment: @RobG Its similar to guide link I added from Microsoft but unfortunately it does not work with OData 8

Comment: Which lines give you errors from that other answer's sample code?  There's some comments on the answer saying there have been _more_ breaking API changes since then, and specifies how to work around that.

Comment: If I use example from your link, there are errors for `GetPathHandler()`, `GetUrlHelper()`, `GetRequestContainer()` and field `ODataFeature().RouteName`

Comment: can [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/routing-in-asp-net-core-8-0-preview/) help you?

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately this blog post does not talk about creating entity relations through odata. I did refer it earlier though while reading about upgrading to OData 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@soccer7, the *guide* you are referring to is for OData with ASP.NET Web API (2.2). That does not apply to OData with ASP.NET Core.

The OData documentation doesn't appear to have been updated with how to extract the key. There *may* be other ways, but the following will definitely work:

```cs
[HttpPut]
public IActionResult CreateRef(
    int key,
    string navigationProperty,
    [FromBody] Uri link )
{
    var feature = HttpContext.ODataFeature();
    var model = feature.Model;
    var serviceRoot = new Uri( new Uri( feature.BaseAddress ), feature.RoutePrefix );
    var requestProvider = feature.Services;
    var parser = new ODataUriParser( model, serviceRoot, link, requestProvider );

    parser.Resolver ??= new UnqualifiedODataUriResolver() { EnableCaseInsensitive = true };
    parser.UrlKeyDelimiter = ODataUrlKeyDelimiter.Slash;

    var path = parser.ParsePath();
    var segment = path.OfType<KeySegment>().Single();
    var otherKey = segment.Keys.Single().Value; // note: could have multiple keys

    // TODO: use 'otherKey'

    return NoContent();
}
```

It took some spelunking, but this is based on what OData does to parse paths (as seen [here](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/blob/4653b4a521ab48f8b95484b9bbf47f5e8ff11ea6/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/Routing/Parser/DefaultODataPathParser.cs)). It's unclear why, but both the corresponding interface and implementation are marked `internal`. With a little extra work, you *could* turn this into an extension method.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris, really appreciate your work! Is there a timeline when we'll have stable version of Asp.Versioining.OData?

Comment: I'm hoping the next 3-4 weeks max. Burn-in has been solid. Coding signing needs to be solved and is slow-going. A bug was also discovered in ASP.NET Core that affects Minimal APIs w/OpenAPI, but otherwise, things are on-track for a stable release.

Comment: Hi! just wanted to check if the timeline for stable version release was changed?

Comment: Still waiting on [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet-foundation/projects/issues/214) to be completed for code signing, but - otherwise - yes. I've been working informal back channels over email too, but it's moving slow. I don't understand the hold-up, but I'm doing what I can to move it forward. Eager to start work for .NET 7 soon. :)